# Does Android have a property like clipsToBounds on iOS?

Tags: android, ios

Does Android have a property like clipsToBounds on iOS; used to display the sub view outside the bounds of the parent view?

Comment: make it clear what u want?

Comment: +1. I came here with this question, and got the answer. It is perfectly normal to ask a functionality in terms of an established and popular functionality that exists in another environment. Anyone who have understanding of both environments understands the question, others dont. "How to find cube root in Java ?", is a valid question regardless whether or not the person who is reading the question is educated enough to know what a cube root is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `setClipChildren` is what you are looking for. See the documentation here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipChildren(boolean)

Comment: setClipChildren in conjunction with setClipToPadding allowed me to draw items out of the container without clipping.